# XSLT Sort without for-each

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

i have the exercise to sort a xml file without using "for-each".
With my script, i get the entrys, but they are not sorted.

The Xml File:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
 xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match="CD">
<br/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="TITLE" >
  <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>

</xsl:template>
```

THX

Answer (score 1):

Because there is only one TITLE in CD I assume you like to sort CD by TITLE:
Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
 xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
<xsl:template match="CATALOG">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="CD" >
     <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CD">
  <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
  <br/>
</xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your templates are a bit wrong... First of all you dont have a root matching template and second of all you're iterating over `TITLE` while you should iterate over `CD`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version = '1.0'
 xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CD" >
        <xsl:sort select="TITLE"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CD">
    <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
</xsl:template>
```

The output you're seing is probably not being generated by your templates but by the default template being applied to `/`.